# Windows Datacenter 2016 GUI edition - Can not add my other windows 2016 servers to the domain. Error DNS name not found?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-domain, windows-server-2016

I am in a Windows Server Administration class.I am using virtualbox. I'm having trouble adding users to my domain. I have two networks, a NAT network and an internal network. Both are configured properly. I can ping ServerDC1 from ServerDM1 using both 192.168.0.5/24 and 192.168.1.1/24. I can also ping ServerDM1 from ServerDC1 using the same method, but with 192.168.0.6/24, and 192.168.1.2/24. I am really stumped. Could I have installed AD DS incorrectly? I have my Domain Controller configured with AD DS and DNS, I made sure to configure some DNS forwarders as well. Any ideas as to how I would add the other servers to the domain?

[This is an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1kyo.png)

Comment: What DNS servers is the client using? Note that the error message has nothing to do about the server's pingability, it literally means the client is unable to do a DNS lookup.

Comment: My NAT network on ServerDC1 is using ::1, 127.0.0.1, and 8.8.8.8 as a secondary. I believe I have it set to the loopback address because I have the DNS configured on the domain controller. My internal network on ServerDC1 is using only ::1. I believe it uses the gateway of the domain controller when left unconfigured. That should be okay though since the DC is also the dns server, right?

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you're trying to join ServerDM1, not ServerDC1. To rephrase: What DNS servers is the _planned domain member_ (ServerDM1) using?

Comment: Sorry about that, I misunderstood. For ServerDM1 The internal adapter configuration uses 192.168.0.1 which is the gateway to my ServerDC1. The Private network adapter configuration uses no dns configuration, so it defaulted to three ipv6 addresses with percentages at the end of them. One of them looks like this: ( fec0:0:0:ffff: :1%1 ) They are all the same aside from the last portion, which is 1%1, 2%1, and 3%1.

Answer (score 1):

Through the questions grawity asked me, I looked at my configuration. The problem was my dns configuration for ServerDM1 was set to the gateway of the domain controller, not the ip address of the domain controller. I changed the dns configuration to the correct address, and I am now connected to my domain. Thank you for your help.